# I can't use typed js in my vue js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I try to call typed in my main.js, the router and the typed are down :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from '@/router'
import VueTypedJs from 'vue-typed-js'

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);
app.use(VueTypedJs);
app.mount('#app');
```

Do you know why?

I try different way to call vue typed js but any can resolve this issue !

For sure I install before :  npm install --save vue-typed-js
and  I use it ( that from the doc, exemple ) :

```
<vue-typed-js :strings="['First text', 'Second Text']">
  <h1 class="typing"></h1>
</vue-typed-js>
```

Comment: Show in the console and read the error message

Comment: @Marc this is the message : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_c'). The object don't exist but I don't know why : (

Comment: The last contribution on `vue-typed-js` was 4 years ago. This means it's not compatible with Vue3. It only works with Vue2. It might be possible to make it work with Vue3, but you'll likely need to write the integration plugin yourself.

Comment: ok thx you man I didn't see that !

Answer (score 2):

The last contribution on [vue-typed-js](https://github.com/Orlandster/vue-typed-js) has been more than 3.5 years ago (April 2019).

Which means it only works with Vue2. It might be possible to make it work with Vue3, but you'll likely need to write the [integration plugin](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html) yourself.

---

Note: I'm guessing someone will take the time to write a Vue3 compatible version at some point. Please let me know, so I can keep the answer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As @tao asked, there's a npm package for this that is compatible with vue3: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@duskmoon/vue3-typed-js

There are some issues with like you cant use it with slots or dynamic components, only static html element as a container. Or maybe I just couldnt find the right way to make it. But still its the only package I found

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to use **typed.js** in VueJS-3:

```
<template>
    <span id="typedMessage" class="typed">{{ typed }}</span>
</template>

<script>
import Typed from 'typed.js';

export default {
   name: '',
   data() {
      return {
         typed: ''
      };
   },
   mounted() {
      this.typed = new Typed('#typedMessage', {
         strings: ['Designer', 'Developer', 'Freelancer'],
         typeSpeed: 50,
      });
   }
}
</script>
```